# Tab switching in IOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I have two tabs in my application. I implemented the tabs with *UITabBarController*. I can switch between the two tabs using the tab bar in the application. But I want to use buttons to switch between tabs. Both tab will contain one button. Pressing the button in any tab will switch to the other tab. I cant seem to find any way to do this.Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply make a button graphic and use that button graphic inside your tabs of your tab bar?  :-)

Comment: I just want to learn how to switch between tabs manually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to switch between tabs using code, it can be as simple as changing the ["`selectedIndex`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex) property of your UITabBarController (provided that controller is hooked up to an outlet your view controller can address).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like:-

```
BOOL isFirstIndexSelected;
-(IBAction)ActionSwitchTab
{

    if(isFirstIndexSelected=YES)
    {
      [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
      isFirstIndexSelected==NO;
    }
    else

    {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
          isFirstIndexSelected==YES;

    }

}
```

As for above code its for only one button clicking changing tab. But if you set Diffrent  button for Diffrent tab you just need to implements each button action and set tab manually like :-

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];`

Comment: bet where you done its another answer not my answer..but its ok if you think MICHAEL answer better then help's my answer then no issue

Comment: I noticed your answer later :) Your answer works too! Thanks for replying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19859/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-kalkin)